# adding conditions when scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, conditional-statements

I'm trying to scrape a webpage, and it seems that each separation has a different `div`, depending in how much the user pays or the type of page it has.

Example:

```
<div class="figuration Web company-stats">
..information i want to scrap..
</div>

<div class="figuration Commercial" >
..information i want to scrap..
</div>
```

It seems to have more than 3 types of divs so I wanted to know if there's a way to just select every `div` that contains the first word figuration?

Here is my spider code:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from pagina.items import PaginaItem
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "pagina"
    allowed_domains = ["paginasamarillas.com.co"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.paginasamarillas.com.co/busqueda/bicicletas-medellin"]
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor( restrict_xpaths=('//ul[@class="paginator"]')), 
        callback='parse_item', follow=True, ),
)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = PaginaItem()

        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="figuration Web company-stats"]'):
            item = PaginaItem()
            item['nombre'] = sel.xpath('.//h2[@class="titleFig"]/a/text()').extract()
            #item['lugar'] = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="infoContact"]/div/h3/text()').extract()
            #item['numero'] = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="infoContact"]/span/text()').extract()
            #item['pagina'] = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="infoContact"]/a/@href').extract() 
            #item['sobre'] = sel.xpath('.//p[@class="CopyText"]/div/h3/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CSS selector:

```
for sel in response.css('div.figuration'):
    ...
```

Comment: it worked, but what other methods can it be used with xpath for example.

Comment: @2one2 You can do the same thing with XPath, yes, but it's cleaner with CSS in this case. For more details, see: http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2014/07/17/xpath-tips-from-the-web-scraping-trenches/

Comment: @2one2: Scrapy supports both and you can chain the two: `response.css('...').xpath('...').css('...')`. Just use whatever is easier. In this case, a CSS selector is vastly simpler.

Answer (score 1):

CSS selector mentioned above will work, but if you wish to use xpath selector, you can use it like:

```
for each in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"figuration")]'):
    ...
```

Actually, `response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"figuration")]')` can be used interchangeably with `response.css('div.figuration')`

Comment: Not quite. This matches `<div class="figurations">`, while the CSS selector does not.